# Run commands shows OPENSSL not found

Tags: ssh, openssh

Ubuntu 14.04 x86-64
I'm sorry but this is urgent since may commands/tools is now broken.

ssh command output:

```
ssh: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.1' not found (required by ssh)
ssh: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.0' not found (required by ssh)
```

I googled and seems the libcrypto is related package ssldev, but whatever I remove or install libssl, it still does not work.

```
ls -l /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2923797 Oct 16 15:59 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      18 Oct 16 15:33 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 -> libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

Not just the ssh command fails, other commands that use ssl also fail like pgadmin.

```
pgadmin3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.1' not found (required by pgadmin3)
pgadmin3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.0' not found (required by pgadmin3)
pgadmin3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.0' not found (required by /usr/lib/libpq.so.5)
pgadmin3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.1d' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0)
pgadmin3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.1' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0)
pgadmin3: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: version `OPENSSL_1.0.0' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0)
```

Another point that confused me is my openssl always shows version 1.1.0.

```
openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.0  25 Aug 2016
```

Even if I install openssl from source that version be 1.0.0a, it still be same.

Thank you in advance

Comment: what did you do with that system? Did you try to reinstall `openssl` packages?